# Capistrano Permission denied (publickey). with remote_cache

Tags: ssh, capistrano

I've an issue with capistrano when I want to deploy via remote_cache.
It's works fine on :copy.

I got this error :

```
[ssh.alwaysdata.com] executing command
** [ssh.alwaysdata.com :: err] Permission denied (publickey).
** [ssh.alwaysdata.com :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've well set up my ssh key on my server and on my github & bitbucket accounts … so I don't understand why there is an publickey issue.

Here his the repo of my test project : https://bitbucket.org/valentincaen/deploy_-remote_cache

Thanks,

Valentin

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue, I had simply a passphrase on my ssh key. I generated a new key without passphrase and it's working